# Detecting if flash player is currently playing? - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that involves detecting whether or not an adobe flash player video is current playing or is paused. I'm fairly sure this can be done quite easily with HTML5, but any ideas about other video players?

Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt there is a universal method. Flash video players are opaque "programs", they don't have a universal play/paused state for the video in them exposed anyhow. There is a play/pause state of the flash object itself, I suppose, but this is not connected to the video playback.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt there is a universal method.

Flash video players are opaque "programs" that differ from site to site, they don't have a universal play/paused state for the video in them exposed anyhow.

Your question is therefore like "can I detect whether there is a video player currently playing or paused in Windows", and you can guess that there is little chance for a universal solution.

There is a play/pause state of the flash object itself, I suppose, but this is not connected to the video playback. It's whether the flash object is completely frozen or not. At most you can detect if a flash object is present.

Comment: If I knew the specific websites that I wanted to support then, how would you suggest going about finding if their specific flash object is playing?